Frobenius norm of a product of random projections converging to $1/e$
Suppose $A$ is a $d\times d$ matrix formed by multiplying $d$ random matrices of the form $I-vv^T$ where $v$ is sampled isotropically from the unit sphere.
Empirically it appears that $\frac{1}{d}\|A\|^2_F \approx 1/e$, why?

(related question)

in what sense do you observe this approximation to hold? in expectation over A? with high probability for fixed A?

@SimonSegert With high probability, the table above gives a single sample

Intuition: as $d$ grows large, it becomes more and more likely that any two of the $v$ are very nearly orthogonal.  What if, then, you were to begin with an orthogonal frame and simply select (with replacement) $d$ elements of that frame for your vectors $v$?

@whuber in that case I would get a zero matrix

Not so--the selection is with replacement.  On average, for large $n,$ there would be $1/e$ elements of the frame not selected.
